# Azure vpn loses connection after 1 hour

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I am creating a site to site VPN from Azure to company headquarters.  The Connection comes up fine, but is dropped after exactly 1 hour.  In the Palo Alto logs we can see a timeout value of 3600 secs, which is the default for Policy Based VPN Gateways.  We are using a Route Based VPN Gateway (using BGP), which should have a timeout value of 27,000 secs according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices#ipsec
If we reset the Virtual Network Gateway, the VPN comes up again for exactly an hour.
Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try troubleshooting with Network Watcher and see if you can get any logs from your gateway .

https://www.danielstechblog.io/troubleshoot-azure-vpn-gateways-azure-network-watcher/

If that doesn’t help triple check the configuration of both sides.

Comment: Thanks Jarnstrom good suggestions. Unfortunately we are hitting a bug with Network Watcher where it doesn't capture the correct logs (my colleague has a case open with MS on this for another customer!). What's odd is that a test vpn to another subscription is working fine with the same settings.   That's showing a different sa lifetime value in the PA logs, but was done via the portal rather than with an ARM template,  but template has no extra settings in it!

Comment: @Wayno that’s weird. Could it be that the ARM template targets an older API version?

Comment: That's a great thought @jarnstrom. I am using an older version of the API in the template, that's worth a try